# Getting 'arr[Symbol.iterator] is not a function' when using custom api hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-hooks

I've written a custom hook that makes an api call the returns the result and an error if present. When trying to right a Jest Test for the component that is using the custom hooks I get 'arr[Symbol.iterator] is not a function' or 'Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined' before the hook when using Jest shallow()

I felt this was an issue with the api response working with a promise so I tried various different approaches around .then or 'wait' for aysnc. This doesn't resolve the issue

My Custom api hook

```
/* Packages */
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const useApiCall = (endPoint) => {
    const [hasError, setHasErrors] = useState(false);
    const [fetchData, setFetchData] = useState(null);

    const getData = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(endPoint);

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error(response.statusText);
            }

            const responseJSON = await response.json();

            setFetchData(responseJSON.data);
        }
        catch (error) {
            setHasErrors(true);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    },[])

    return [fetchData, hasError]
}
```

My component using the hook

```
/* Packages */
import React, { useState } from 'react';

/* Utils */
import { useApiCall } from '../../utils/useApiCall';

/* Components */
import FooterStructure from './FooterStructure'

const Footer = () => {
    const [footerLinks, error] = useApiCall('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5d7678f93200000362297bae');
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState();

    const showContent = () => {
        setVisible(!visible);
    }

    const componentProps = {
        footerLinks : footerLinks,
        error : error,
        visible : visible,
        showContent : showContent
    };

    return (
        <FooterStructure {...componentProps} />
    )
};

export default Footer;
```

My Jest test without/with promises

```
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Footer from '.';
import mock from './__mocks__/FooterLinks';
import { useApiCall } from '../../utils/useApiCall';
import { testHook } from '../../utils/TestUtils';

jest.mock('../../utils/useApiCall');

let footerData,
    wrapper;

beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Footer />);

    testHook(async () => {
        useApiCall.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ data: mock }));
        useApiCall().then((resolve)=>{
            footerData = resolve;
        })
        // This promise gives the same error
        // .then(()=>{
        //     wrapper = shallow(<Footer />);
        // })
        // .catch((error)=>{
        //     console.log(error);
        // });
    });
});

describe('Footer links', () => {
    it('should have 3 links', () => {
        expect(footerData.data.length).toEqual(3);
    });
});
```

The error

````
  Footer links
    ✕ should have 3 links (46ms)

  ● Footer links › should have 3 links

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined

       8 | import FooterStructure from './FooterStructure'
       9 | 
    > 10 | const Footer = () => {
         |                      ^
      11 |     const [footerLinks, error] = useApiCall('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5d7678f93200000362297bae');
      12 |     const [visible, setVisible] = useState();
      13 | 

      at _iterableToArrayLimit (node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/iterableToArrayLimit.js:8:22)
      at _slicedToArray (node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/slicedToArray.js:8:33)
      at Footer (src/global/Footer/index.js:10:22)
      at ReactShallowRenderer.render (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer-shallow.development.js:794:32)
      at render (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:636:55)
      at fn (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-utils/src/Utils.js:99:18)
      at Object.render (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:636:20)
      at new render (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:397:22)
      at shallow (node_modules/enzyme/src/shallow.js:10:10)
      at Object.<anonymous>.beforeEach (src/global/Footer/Footer.test.js:14:15)

  ● Footer links › should have 3 links

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

      24 | describe('Footer links', () => {
      25 |     it('should have 3 links', () => {
    > 26 |         expect(footerData.data.length).toEqual(3);
         |                           ^
      27 |     });
      28 | });
      29 | 

      at Object.data (src/global/Footer/Footer.test.js:26:27)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.66s, estimated 1s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.```

My jest test with promise
````

Comment: Limit to one issue instead of posting bunch in one, you are more likely to get an answer.

Comment: It is one issue? The issue is I get this error when trying to use shallow in jest for custom hooks

Comment: I had a similar case where my custom hook didn't have reference to Context it was consuming and was giving me the 'arr[Symbol.iterator] is not a function' at a seemingly unrelated line. Was solved by wrapping it in the Context. I suggest throwing down a `debugger;` and stepping through: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting